# Excel X axis on charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How do you make the x-axis appear like this in Excel 2013:

[image: X-axis]

This picture is from my text book.  It shows a number at each end of each block.  I know how to make the chart, but I am hung up on the x-axis.  It is circled in the attached photo.

Comment: I don't have a ready answer for you, but keep in mind that what's in your textbook isn't a normal chart, it's a histogram.

Comment: Is the issue the interval or the position? A pivot chart might be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to write your Table in 2 columns: Selling Price and Number of vehicles with the corresponding numbers, select the Number of vehicles column and insert a column chart, select the chart and click on Chart Tools, Design, Select Data, Under the Horizontal Category Axis Labels, Click on Edit then select the numbers under Selling Price and Ok.
NB: The Chart will be separated columns